# Booklet Layout Question

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-production, booklet

I am on a deadline to print a booklet for our church choir and am having trouble with the layout. 
I have 12 pages, and am using the print booklet feature, but I need to print this from our printer here in the office, and it is not working to print double-sided. It's flipping the page upside down from the other side and not lining up. So my question is, how do I layout an indesign doc for 2-up saddle stitch so that I can print double sided and put the pages on top of each other to where they line up? Where am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever your duplex setting is, it may need to be the changed. I have had this same problem and [this article](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/324080) helped.

From the article:

> My Canon printer has long side left or right and short side top or bottom staple choices on the duplex settings. I switched from a long side to a short side setting and it worked. I am going to have to study the meaning behind that terminology because it does not make intuitive sense to me.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out, I had the setting set to bind on long edge instead of short edge of paper